# Why isn't a "litmus test" a proper noun?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

A test is a thing, which makes *test* a noun. A *Litmus Test* is a specific type of test so why do I never see it capitalized in example sentences. I would think it is a proper noun. What is wrong with my thinking here?

Comment: It's not a proper noun (or name) so there's no reason to capitalise it.

Comment: Is it not the name of a specific test?

Comment: I'm going with ... the Litmus test judged acid/base, but a litmus test is any binary trial.

Comment: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Litmus+test%2Clitmus+test&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: Would you capitalise "pregnancy test" or "[acid test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_test_(gold))"? Even "driving test" which is prescribed by law isn't generally capitalised (maybe in government documents).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word "Turing" is a person's name, so the word is capitalised in "Turing test". The word "litmus" refers to a chemical; it is not a proper noun and it is not capitalised, whether on its own or as part of a noun phrase such as "litmus paper".

Answer (score 2):

Proper nouns are usually non-descriptive names of individual things (rather than types of things). For example, the name "France" is non-descriptive (knowing that France is called "France" doesn't tell you anything about France), and it refers to one single, individual thing (there's only one country in the entire world that's called France).

On the other hand, the phrase "litmus test" is descriptive (it's a test that uses litmus), and it refers to a *type* of test, rather than to one individual test that was performed once. So there's no reason for it to be a proper noun.